# How to change value of inspecter scale using c#

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to change the inspectors values like scale?
Can i do it with a script?

Each time I have to generate obstacles with different scale values im realy new to unity so more explanation is needed the code for obstacle is written here:

```
    using UnityEngine;
public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    //rigi=GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(-4, 0);
    public float r;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - r * Random.value, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want just change the GameObject' scale in a script? `transform.localScale.Set(newX,newY,newZ)`

Comment: i have used it with this 'codeusing UnityEngine;

public class Generate : MonoBehaviour
{
 public GameObject rocks;
 
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
  InvokeRepeating("Hell", 1f,2f);
 }
 
 void Hell()
 {
  Instantiate(rocks);
  transform.localScale.Set (5, 3, 1);
 }
}

Comment: it not works it a pacaked obstacle

Comment: ok... you must save every new instanciated "rock" in some variable. (an gameObject array should be the perfect place). Then, use this variable to acces to its properties:

`GameObject[] rockArray=new GameObject [MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROCKS];`

`//etc `
void Hell(){
`n++;`
`rockArray[n]=Instanciate(rocks);`
`rockArray[n].transform.localScale.Set (5, 3, 1);`

Comment: shall i give it in the same generate code?

Comment: Depending on the type of game you want to do, maybe it's better to instantiate your "rocks" in separate variables, arrays, in ListArrays ... Perhaps you  think is better to instantiate the arrays in the header of the script, or the function Start () ... there are a lot of combinations. Enjoy experiencing. Also I recommend the Unity official video tutorials about [instantiation](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/instantiate) and about [Arrays](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/arrays)

Comment: will check it and inform you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to change an objects scale in script is use:

```
theObject.transform.localScale.Set(x, y,z);
```

You could change it in the start of your script, or make methods that increase or decrease the scale that you can call from other scripts.

Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: do i need to attach the script with the component?

Comment: You need to have the scale tranform code in a script attatched to the object that you want to scale yes. After that it just depends on how and when you call the code, depending on the result you want. If you need more detail try giving me a more detailed account of what you are specifically trying to accomplish and I can give you advice more useful to your situation.

Comment: this is how arranged the assets

Comment: You need to clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish here. Which object do you want to scale? Is the script attached to that object?

Comment: the obstacle rock up and rock down you can clearly see it in images im using obstacle script to make the object obstacle and also uses a generate scipt to regenerate the the rocks the combined game object is added into geenrate sript and i ise instantianate to recall eacch time

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject rock;
 int i=0;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
 
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  rock.transform.localScale.Set (i, i + 9, i + 2);

  i++;
 }
}

Comment: I am sorry but none of what you are saying is clear. If the scaling script in on the rock object, why is the rock object not in the scene? When it is in the scene, what happens? How does the result differ from the result you are looking for. If you want clear and accurate help you need to give a clear description of what you want to happen and what is currently happening. What do you mean when you say the script regenerates the rocks?

Comment: this is the tutorial im following he just using spacebar so i have changed it to click(touch) control

Comment: Ok I read the tutorial. Please tell me what part you are having a problem with. Be specific as to what the problem is, as in what part are you trying to do, and what is happening in your game versus what you want to happen in the game.

Comment: I dont understand why you want to scale the objects. In the tutorial they just spawn the rocks and thats it.

Comment: i would like to generate custom size rocks does changing the scale values do it?

Comment: Yes changing the scale of the rocks will change the size of them in the scene. All you need to do is generate the rocks exactly the same way as they are generated in the tutorial, and add a randomized scaling command in the script controlling the rocks themselves. Could you show me the script controlling the rocks, and how you have the script attatched in the inspector?

Comment: using UnityEngine;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
 GameObject rock;
 //rigi=GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(-4, 0);
 public float r;
 int i=0;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
  GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity;
  transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - r * Random.value, transform.position.z);

  rock.transform.localScale.Set (i, i + 9, i + 2);
  i++;
 }
}

Comment: Take a screenshot of the script please. Also include a screenshot of the inspector of the script object in your scene, so I can see how you have configured it.

Comment: the whole thing is uploaded kindly check it im realy new to this

Comment: So in the Scripts game object, you need to assign the rocks game object. Check the generate script that is attatched to your script object, and you will see that there is a field called rocks, that says missing game object. Drag your obstacle game object rocks into that field to assign it. Otherwise the generate script does not know what to instantiate.

Comment: thanks it worked how can i delete the cloned prefabs? does it will eat memory? how can i manage it?

Comment: It is possible to delete the objects after you are done with them, but in your case it is not needed. They will not have a noticable impact on performace with such a small game, depending on how long the level keeps spawning them. If you do want to have them destroyed here is how you do it. First you will want to create a Die() method in the script, and add a [Destroy()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) in the method. Then call that method when the object either A: hits a cleanup collider off the back side of the screen or B: gets called on start with delay

Comment: Also please remember to accept the answer I provided above by clicking the green checkmark button, thanks!

Comment: void Start()
 {
  GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity;
  transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y - r * Random.value, transform.position.z);
  Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
  {
   Destroy(this.gameObject);
  }
 }
does this work?

Comment: Its a little hard to tell if the script will work when it is posted in comment format. Could you take a screenshot?